# SQL Query outputting "yes"

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm studying for my Database System exam tomorrow, and I'm working on an SQL question. This question is the only one from the paper that doesn't have an answer, but here's the question:

---

We use the following schema:

- *Professor*(name, office, dept, age) (age is key)
- *Course*(cno, title, dept) (cno stands for course number and is a key, title is the name of the course and dept is name of department offering the course)
- *Enrollment*(cno, semester, inst_name, enrollment) (the key for this is (cno, semester)

**Question: Write the following sql query: Output a table containing the single row "yes" in it if the age difference between the oldest and the youngest professors teaching the Database Systems course between 2000 and 2009 is at most 5 years**

---

I amn't sure my approach is right, since we don't exactly want to output something from the table. Note that I think enrollment corresponds to when the instructor started teaching the course (which isn't the usual definition AFAIK).

My approach is as follows:

```
WITH dbsProfs AS (
    SELECT P.age
    FROM Professor P, Enroll E, Course C
    WHERE P.name = E.inst_name AND C.cno = E.cno AND C.title = "Database Systems"
        AND E.enrollment BETWEEN 2000 and 2009
    )
SELECT "Yes"
FROM dbsProfs
WHERE MAX(dbsProfs.age) - MIN(dbsProfs.age) <= 5
```

I'm fairly confident with my temporary table. I'm doing a join on all 3 tables and filtering out to include only the ones relevant to my query. It's the other half I'm unsure about.

Any insight on whether this is correct/how to correct this would be much appreciated. I amn't convinced `WHERE MAX(dbsProfs.age) - MIN(dbsProfs.age) <= 5` is valid SQL

Comment: Post the question, the site is blocked for some of us.

Comment: @sagi I apologize. The post has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With aggregate function  you shoud use having

```
 SELECT "Yes"
 FROM dbsProfs
 HAVING MAX(dbsProfs.age) - MIN(dbsProfs.age) <= 5
```

Comment: Why the hell did `HAVING` escape my mind???? I've used it for the past 3 questions god damnit. Will this return nothing (empty table) if that condition isn't satisfied? Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH dbsProfs AS (
    SELECT MIN(P.age) as min_age,MAX(P.age) as max_age
    FROM Professor P, Enroll E, Course C
    WHERE P.name = E.inst_name AND C.cno = E.cno AND C.title = "Database Systems"
        AND E.enrollment BETWEEN 2000 and 2009
    )
SELECT CASE WHEN min_age<max_age THEN "Yes" END
FROM dbsProfs
```

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen the `WHEN ... THEN ... END` statements being used in a query. I guess they call this a beginner Database System class for a reason :). Is there any way at all to represent it using `WHERE` or is that just not possible? Thanks for this suggestion :)

Comment: I take back what I said. I've used cases only once, but still slipped my mind. This is a great way, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

It's true, you can't put aggregate functions in your WHERE statement.  This question will take a bit more work.

This is the approach I would take:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN A.MaxAge - A.MinAge <=5 THEN "Yes" END
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Max(Professor.age) AS MaxAge, Min(Professor.age) AS MinAge
        FROM Professor INNER JOIN Enroll ON Professor.name = Enroll.inst_name 
        INNER JOIN Course ON Enroll.cno = Course.cno
        WHERE Course.title = "Database Systems" AND Enroll.enrollment BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
    ) AS A
```

This assumes enrollment is indeed the year the course was instructed (as you also assumed).  You can use an `iif` statement if you're fond of SQL Server instead of the SELECT CASE (the latter being more t-SQL standards friendly).